# Resetting TestRPC Genesis Block

Tags: testrpc

Is there a way to reset the genesis block in my testrpc? I keep getting an 'out of gas error' and I think that resetting would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resets everything every time you start it. More likely, the contract throws and the error is misleading. Another tip, every time you restart testrpc, redeploy your contracts. They are not there, so it will eat gas.

Comment: Thanks! So what is weird is that the contract works in Remix, but breaks locally. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: it might help someone spot the error if you post deployment steps and transaction execution steps. TestRPC does a few things automatically for developer convenience. For example, to deploy via geth, you need a funded and unlocked account to pay for gas. That implies a few preliminaries before attempting a test. Error's that bubble up from Geth may be hard to interpret.